# Can I simplify the member functions in a cout statement

Tags: c++, member-functions

I need help in simplifying the member functions in this code. How do I not have to set the width and justification without doing it for every variable?

```
while (in_file >> color >> category >> age >> value) {
            cout.width(10);
            cout.setf(ios::right);
            cout << color;
            cout.width(10);
            cout.setf(ios::right);
            cout << category;
            cout.width(10);
            cout.setf(ios::right);
            cout << age;
            cout.width(10);
            cout.setf(ios::right);
            cout << value << endl;
        }
```

Comment: How about a template function?

Comment: What about this: onlinegdb.com/ry7ioJTvd - you can even mix r10out and cout statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one line statement to implement the above requirements.

Using setw() from iomanip.

```
cout << right << setw(10) << color << setw(10) << category << setw(10) << age << setw(10) << value << endl;
```